# Dropdown is not getting close in the Lightning Input box in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, html, inputfield, lightninginput

Hi I have created the lightning input box which contains some value as a drop down but when i am clicking outside of the drop down anywhere on the page the values which are appearing as a drop down is not getting  closed.

```
   <lightning-input label='testSearch' onfocus={handleoneItem} onchange={handleOneItem}
                                onkeydown={handle2item} value={testaccountNu} type='search'
                                maxlength='100' 
                                placeholder='Select test ' 
                                 class='slds-combobox__input'>
                            </lightning-input>
```

Comment: Allen for creating a dropdown the right component would be combobox.

Comment: Yes i know but as per req. i need to create the custom one.

Comment: Then I would suggest using the `select` tag of HTML which is explicitly for creating dropdown and the behaviour is handled by the browser.

Comment: select will not support other methods of lighting..!!

Comment: is there anyway i can shift focus to another field on click of the mouse or click of the dropdown

Comment: `other methods of lighting` ? the more custom you go, the further away you want to stay from lightning lwc components. as suggested by manjit, you should use html tags for this.